# Can't clearTimeOut

Tags: javascript

I have a TimeOut which doesn't stop once clear is used on it and I am unsure why.

This is my function:

```
function upgrade_bar(end, start, bar, timerId, func) {      

    var per = ( (new Date().getTime() / 1000) - start ) / ( end - start ) * 100;

    if(per>100)per=100;
    if(per<0)per = 0;

    if(per == 0) {
        bar.style.width = per + "%";
    } else if(per == 100) {
        clearTimeout(timerId); //this does not stop it
        if(func !== false){
            func(); //this does call at 100%
        }
    } else{
        bar.style.width = per+ "%";
    }
    console.log('still going');
    timerId = setTimeout(function() { upgrade_bar(end, start, bar, timerId, func) } , 17);
}
```

What have i misunderstood about this? Doesn't timerId hold the Id of the timeout for me to clear it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout()` just schedules **one more** execution of the function.

`clearTimeout()` can be used to stop an upcoming timeout **before** the time is reached - but once the timeout is reached and the function has been called, clearing the timeout does nothing - it wasn't going to run again anyways.

The problem here is that regardless of what happens in your function, you end by calling setTimeout again - scheduling it to run again.

---

A possible solution is to rewrite your function like this:

```
function upgrade_bar(end, start, bar, func){       
    var per = ( (new Date().getTime() / 1000) - start ) / ( end - start ) * 100;
    if (per>100) per=100;
    if (per<0) per = 0;

    bar.style.width = per + "%";

    if (per == 100) {
        if (func !== false) {
            func(); //this does call at 100%
        }
    } else {
        console.log('still going');
        setTimeout(function() { upgrade_bar(end, start, bar, func) } , 17);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah so i was confusing it with SetInterval. Ok a simple `return false` should end it then instead of clearing it ?
Also why does clearTimeOut even exist then, what use would it have.

Comment: @Dave one place I've seen clearTimeout used is in an autocomplete. When a key is pressed, you start the timeout for say 500ms, but cancel it if the user types another character. That way, it won't actually execute until nothing has been typed for 500ms.

Comment: @Dave I've updated my answer to explain it. Basically, clearTimeout can be called before the time is reached in order to cancel it.

Comment: Ah i see they should of named it something like "AbortTimeOut" to avoid the confusing with SetInterval's version

Comment: @Dave Yes, abort is a better description of what it does.

Comment: @Dave - I use it to determine the difference between a click-drag and a long-click for an interactive canvas-based app. It's also useful for aborting HTTP requests if they don't finish in a reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout()` causes one execution of the specified function. You're thinking of `setInterval()`, which executes until canceled.

In your case, `clearTimeout()` is called, but the code continues on to set another timeout, no matter what code path is taken.

Try `return`ing after calling `func()` to avoid setting the timeout again.

Comment: So what does clearTimeOut() actually do i see no purpose for in JS